# How to create the video timeline in video editing app

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, video-processing

I am currently developing a small video editing app that uses flutter for UI development and I am struggling with the video timeline. I tried using `Row` for display images and wrapping it with a `SingleChildScrollView` and then I tried to use the `ScrollController` to indicate the current playing position, seeking the specific position and etc. But it is more complex when implementing the above functions. Does anyone know another approach to implement this feature?

[image]

Comment: This is too vague and generic, but to give you a hint you have to support multiple time conversions (ms, fps, bpm etc). The timeline in such an app would be 0.0001% of your worries anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To implement timeline I suppose you can use [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) data structure. Learn more about it [here](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/public_user/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).